# TypeError: _food2.default is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, class, webpack, import, webpack-dev-server

I have an issue with my `Food` class I created for a food tracker I want to create. It is working fine in one file but not in the other.

This is the class:

```
import uuidv4 from 'uuid/v4'
import moment from 'moment'
import { throwIfNotAString, throwIfNotANumber } from './functions'

class Food {
    constructor(id, ean, createdAt, updatedAt, brand, name, calories, protein, carbohydrate, fat, saturatedFat, multipleUnsaturatedFat, basicUnsaturatedFat, transFat, cholesterol, natrium, potassium, fibers, sugar, portion, portionUnit, portionAmount, names, brands) {
        const timestamp = moment().valueOf()
        this._id = id || uuidv4()
        this._ean = ean || null
        this.createdAt = createdAt || timestamp
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt || timestamp
        this._brand = brand.trim()
        this._name = name.trim()
        this._calories = calories
        this._protein = protein
        this._carbohydrate = carbohydrate
        this._fat = fat
        this._saturatedFat = saturatedFat || null
        this._multipleUnsaturatedFat = multipleUnsaturatedFat || null
        this._basicUnsaturatedFat = basicUnsaturatedFat || null
        this._transFat = transFat || null
        this._cholesterol = cholesterol || null
        this._natrium = natrium || null
        this._potassium = potassium || null                             // Kalium
        this._fibers = fibers || null                                   // Ballaststoffe
        this._sugar = sugar || null
        this._portion = portion || null                                 // e.g. 100
        this._portionUnit = portionUnit || null                         // e.g. 'g'
        this._portionAmount = portionAmount || 1                                         
        this._names = names || []
        this._names.push(this._name)
        this._brands = brands || []
        this._brands.push(this._brand)
    }

    get id() {
        return this._id
    }

    get ean() {
        return this._ean
    }

    get brand() {
        return this._brand
    }

    get name() {
        return this._name
    }

    get calories() {
        return this._calories
    }

    get macronutrients() {
        return {
            protein: this._protein,
            carbohydrate: this._carbohydrate,
            fat: this._fat
        }
    }

    set ean(value) {
        if (typeof value === 'number') {
            this._ean = value
            this.updatedAt = moment().valueOf()
        } else if (typeof value !== 'number') {
            throwIfNotANumber('EAN')
        }
    }

    set brand(value) {
        if (typeof value === 'string') {
            this._brand = value.trim()
            this._brands.push(this._brand)
            this.updatedAt = moment().valueOf()
        } else if (typeof value !== 'string') {
            throwIfNotAString('Brand')
        }
    }

    set name(value) {
        if (typeof value === 'string') {
            this._name = value.trim()
            this._names.push(this._name)
            this.updatedAt = moment().valueOf()
        } else if (typeof valule !== 'string') {
            throwIfNotAString('Name')
        }
    }

    set calories(value) {
        if (typeof value === 'number') {
            this._calories = value
            this.updatedAt = moment().valueOf()
        } else if (typeof value !== 'number') {
            throwIfNotANumber('Calories')
        }
    }

    set protein(value) {
        if (typeof value === 'number') {
            this._protein = value
            this.updatedAt = moment().valueOf()
        } else if (typeof value !== 'number') {
            throwIfNotANumber('Protein')
        }
    }

    set carbohydrate(value) {
        if (typeof value === 'number') {
            this._carbohydrate = value
            this.updatedAt = moment().valueOf()
        } else if (typeof value !== 'number') {
            throwIfNotANumber('Carbohydrate')
        }
    }

    set fat(value) {
        if (typeof value === 'number') {
            this._fat = value
            this.updatedAt = moment().valueOf()
        } else if (typeof value !== 'number') {
            throwIfNotANumber('Fat')
        }
    }

    set portion(value) {
        if (typeof value === 'number') {
            this._portion = value
            this.updatedAt = moment().valueOf()
        } else if (typeof value !== 'number') {
            throwIfNotANumber('Portion')
        }
    }
}

export { Food as default }
```

I am exporting it as default.

I use it in my `index.js` file and it is working properly. Here is the extract:

```
import Food from './food'

[...]

const food = new Food(null, null, null, null, brandName, foodName, calories, protein, carbohydrate, fat)

console.log(food) // instance will be logged -> Works as expected
console.log(Food) // Class will be logged -> Works as expected
```

So until here everything is working as expected. In addition I want to use this class in another file called `functions.js` to pass data I stored in local storage again into it (because otherwise my getters and setters are not working, since the logic is gone). And here it is not working anymore.

Here is the exstract:

```
import Food from './food'

console.log(Food) // logs 'undefined' -> is not working as expected

const newFood = new Food(null, null, null, null, 'Schöller', 'Eis', 200, 15, 45, 10)
console.log(newFood) // logs this:
/*
TypeError: _food2.default is not a constructor[Weitere Informationen] functions.js:239:16
./src/functions.js
functions.js:239:16
__webpack_require__
bootstrap:19
./src/food.js
food.js:3
__webpack_require__
bootstrap:19
./src/index.js
index.js:1
__webpack_require__
bootstrap:19
0
http://127.0.0.1:8080/scripts/index-bundle.js:37929:18
__webpack_require__
bootstrap:19
<anonym>
bootstrap:68
<anonym>
http://127.0.0.1:8080/scripts/index-bundle.js:1:11
*/
```

The files are organized like this:

[image]

My `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: ['babel-polyfill', './src/index.js'],
        editFood: ['babel-polyfill', './src/editFood.js'],
        editMeal: ['babel-polyfill', './src/editMeal.js']
    }, 
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/scripts'),
        filename: '[name]-bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/, // Regular Expression
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['env'],
                    plugins: ['transform-object-rest-spread']
                }
            }
        }]
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
        publicPath: '/scripts/'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map'
}
```

I did some research regarding importing with webpack and so on and as far as I see I am importing it correctly. Just to be sure I tried it with naming exports as well with the same result. What am I missing here? In addition I found some similar issues regarding the error message but they has issues with importing the function correctly. I hope, somebody can give me a hint?

Comment: Post project structure

Comment: I added an image how the files are organized to the post.

Comment: Everything looks fine, it's probably your `webpack.config.js` configuration that needs some editing

Comment: @Pavlo okay, I added my `webpack.config.js` as well.

Comment: This is hard to debug without sitting with the code at hand, try setting a breakpoint at function.js:239, it finds `_food2.default`, so at least it has compiled something to be able give that error. I haven't worked with multiple output files, so i am sorry i can't help you more :/

Comment: it probably happens because you have imported functions from `functions` file in `Food`, and then trying to import it in functions again which is circular dependency.

Comment: @HikmatGurbanli you are a genius. That was the issue. Now I put my error messages into a complete new file `errorMessages.js` and imported it properly into the the `food.js` file and that solved it! Thank you very much!